# Chef Inspec throws Rspec deprecation errors

Tags: ruby, rspec, chef-infra, inspec

I'm running a Chef Inspec exec profile in a Jenkins job and it returns Rspec deprecation warnings. The problem is that these warnings are included in the json output that inspec exec command creates and I've tried sed/awk to remove all characters outside of the json object using begin and end pattern /{/ , /}/ but nothing is working, every time  the text is still in the file. I added an rspec exception to the spec_helper.rb file to allow syntax for both but the warnings still appear. I'm left with a file that contains :

```
Invalid expiration date or inactive date or both
Invalid expiration date or inactive date or both

1 deprecation warning total
{"version":"0.30.0","profiles":{  ..... }- this part is actually valid json, excluding from this post to keep it short.
```

Using Inspec 0.30.0, Ruby 2.0.0p645, Rspec 3.5.2.

Here is the command I'm using to execute the inspec profiles on a local target via ssh :

```
    VmIp=$(vmrun getGuestIPAddress output-vmware-iso/${templateName}.vmx -wait)
    inspec exec  ./inspecRepo/ --format json-min -t ssh://vagrant@${VmIp} --password vagrant --sudo | tee Test_Results.json
```

Here is a snippet of the Jenkins job output :

```
+ VmPath=/app_2/jenkins-work/workspace/xl-release/output-vmware-iso/rhel7.vmware.template.vmx
++ vmrun getGuestIPAddress output-vmware-iso/rhel7.vmware.template.vmx -wait
+ VmIp=172.16.81.159
+ inspec exec ./inspecRepo/ --format json -t ssh://vagrant@172.16.81.159 --password vagrant --sudo
+ tee Test_Results.json
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: already initialized constant #<Class:0x00000001a25ac0>::BASELINE
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: previous definition of BASELINE was here
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: already initialized constant #<Class:0x00000001a25ac0>::BASELINE
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: previous definition of BASELINE was here
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: already initialized constant #<Class:0x00000001a25ac0>::BASELINE
./inspecRepo/controls/filesystem.rb:60: warning: previous definition of BASELINE was here

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from ./inspecRepo/controls/app_config.rb:466:in `block (4 levels) in load'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.
Invalid expiration date or inactive date or both
Invalid expiration date or inactive date or both

1 deprecation warning total
{"version":"0.30.0","profiles":{"rhel7-baseline":{ ..............
```

Here is a snippet of the spec_helper.rb where I have added :should & :expect syntax inclusion :

```
   Spec_helper.rb :
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
config.expect_with(:rspec){|c| c.syntax = [:should, :expect]}
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
```

Here is the test that is generating the syntax warnings: 
\

```
    control 'password-inactive' do

  impact 0.5

  title "Ensure password inactivity is configured"

  desc "The password inactive in /etc/shadow is configured"



  DATE_FMT = '%b %d, %Y' # date format used by chage(1) as specified by strptime(3)

  command('egrep ^[^:]+:[^\!*] /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1').stdout.each_line do |line|   # extract all users(username) with password



    pwExipre = command("chage --list #{line}").stdout.split("\n")[1].split(":")[1].strip  # extract date and convert to right format

    pwInactive = command("chage --list #{line}").stdout.split("\n")[2].split(":")[1].strip

    if pwExipre == 'never' || pwInactive == 'never'

      puts "Invalid expiration date or inactive date or both"

      describe true do

        it { should eq false }

      end

    else

      expire = Date.strptime(pwExipre, DATE_FMT) # convert to desired format

      inactive = Date.strptime(pwInactive, DATE_FMT)

      describe (inactive - expire) do

        it { should eq 30 } # 30 days' difference

      end

    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your code to use the new `expect()` or `is_expected` syntax instead. Seems easier and that's the standard moving forward anyway. If you include the actual test code that fails I could be more specific.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the test but the test is using the  standard Inspec dsl.

Comment: Replace `should` with `is_expected.to` or `expect(subject).to`. This is unrelated to InSpec, it's normal RSpec stuffs.

Comment: Hmm, but there are hundreds of tests  in that profile using this Inspec dsl syntax 'should' and they aren't throwing this error.

Comment: You aren't really using InSpec correctly to start with, so I'm unshocked you are having inconsistent results :)